# bash: how do I concatenate the output of two commands so that I can pipe them to a third?

Tags: bash, shell, mercurial, awk, concatenation

```
$ hg status
```

and

```
$ hg status --ignored
```

give very similar outputs. I'd like to concatenate them so I can feed them to awk, as if there were an **hg status --all** (or svn's **svn status --no-ignore**)

I'm thinking something like:

```
$ echo "$(hg status)" "$(hg status --ignored)" | awk  ' ( $1 == "?" ) || ( $1 == "I") { print $2 }' | xargs rm -r
```

to make a 'make very clean indeed' command, but it seems to occasionally leave a file behind, perhaps because a newline goes missing or something.

Comment: If you replace `rm` with `echo` (or skip the last pipe), then what is the output and what should it have been? Also, there might be permission issues where `rm` refuses to delete a file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a subshell:

```
( hg status; hg status --ignored ) | awk '( $1 == "?" ) || ( $1 == "I") { print $2 }' | xargs rm -r
```

Comment: There's no need to use a subshell (another process). Instead you can use braces to group: `{ a; b; } | c`

Comment: I see no meaningful speed difference `time { git branch; git branch -r; } > /dev/null; time (git branch; git branch -r) > /dev/null`  in fact subshell is consistently faster on my system — so @camh, what is is the advantage of a group?

Comment: @MarkFox: It's likely measurement error. The group has one less `fork()` than the subshell. It is very hard to measure a single run of things like this. You want to run it 1000 times or more to get a good feel for the performance. When I do that, the group comes out at 1.69s and the subshell at 2.36s, which is about 40% slower.

Answer (score 30):

Use [curly braces to group commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html):

```
$ { echo first line; echo second line; } | grep "line"
first line
second line
```

(Posted as an answer from [camh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499013/bash-how-do-i-concatenate-the-output-of-two-commands-so-that-i-can-pipe-them-to#comment9080594_7499070))

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  This is what I was looking for, trying to concatenate headers to pass to `sendmail -t` along with output of another command.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the rest of the hg status flags to show what you really want:

```
hg status -uriamn
```

That shows unknown files (u), removed files (r), ignored (i), added (a), modified (m) and does so without showing the status prefix.

Comment: +1 I just wrote down "why not try `hg st -iu|awk ...`?" and saw your answer shows up...

Comment: And I would have posted sooner, but I was trying to make an amusing anagram out of the flags ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
echo $(a)$(b)
```

if you add "" you can add delimiters eg.:

```
echo "$(./gethostname.sh)|($(./getip.sh);"
```

I use this on Openwrt to broadcast my ip settings:

```
echo "$( uci get system.@system[0].hostname )|$( ip addr | grep inet | grep br-lan | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d '/' -f 1 );"  | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:4999,broadcast ;
```